JavaScript for preloading images in the background/cache with progress bar
I am trying to get the data-value of the .ldBar.label-center div to update along with the loading progress of the images loaded in the background, within preloadImages.
I guess my goal would be to get the eventListener to update the data-value object live, so that people waiting can follow the progress of the huge pile of images they have to download into cache before entering the content of the page.


this.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", preloadImages, true);

var imageArray = new Array("bigImage.jpg");

function preloadImages(e) {
  for (var i = 0; i < imageArray.length; i++) {
    var tempImage = new Image();

    tempImage.addEventListener("load", trackProgress, true);
    tempImage.src = imageArray[i];
  }
}

function trackProgress() {
  loadedImages++;
  if (loadedImages == imageArray.length) {
    imagesLoaded();
  }
}

function imagesLoaded() {
  // do something
}
.ldBar-label {
  color: #ffffff;
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  font-size: 5em;
  font-weight: 900;
  -webkit-text-stroke: 3px black;
}

.ldBar path.mainline {
  /* styling of bar omitted */
}
<div class="ldBar label-center" data-value="60" data-type="fill" data-img="media/886679_9d816.gif" data-img-size="400,400" data-fill-background="#9df"></div>




Can you please explain what the actual issue is supposed to be here? You said you were trying to update this attribute - but I can't see any attempt to do so, in your shown JS code?

If you have a "huge number of images" to load, then consider using lazy-loading to only load them when they come into view.  Also consider progressive loading to load low-resolution versions first.

Alternatively, if there are a lot of very small images (eg for a game), then consider using a sprite sheet instead.

Some information regarding this particular project: I´m making a VR house with lots of highres images, hanging on the walls and it was a nightmare on ios phones because it just crashed after loading some of the images. This script loads the sceenes perfectly but I just want the customers to be able to see the progress of the downloading af all images. Lazy-loading is a good sugestion @fdom-m but I rather go for this approach I think. I just cant get my head around the runtime update of the text object here.

To update data attributes, use the dataset property:
const bar = document.querySelector(".ldBar");
bar.dataset.value = loadedImages;


Thanks johnnyaug :) This is so different from what I´m used to in LUA programming so I feel really stupid here. Should I put these lines inside the eventListener for it to update seamlessly or should I put it somewhere else in the code?

This would go in trackProgress directly after loadedImages++

I´m so glad that you help me :) The only thing now is to get the <div class="ldBar label-center" data-value to actually update on the screen

@HenrikRuud you failed to mention what library you are using there for this progress bar, but based on the class names used in the HTML, I am guessing it is https://loading.io/progress? Then go see https://loading.io/progress/#api
